# strength reduction leading to different outcomes with respect to signaling NaNs

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

`gcc` strength-reduces floating-point expressions such as `x * 1.0` into the identity function. This is correct if `x` is a finite or infinite value, but if `x` is a signaling NaN, `x * 1.0` will be a "quietified" version of it. Thus, the outcomes differ depending on whether this strength-reduction has been applied.

I was wondering whether this optimization, which changes observable behavior of the program (the NaN payload is changed), is allowed. Annex F of the C standard says that the behavior of signaling NaN is unspecified, but it's unclear to me if this allows replacing a value by a different one.

This is observable by executing the following program depending on the `EXTERN_MUL` macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#ifdef __COMPCERT__
#define float_of_bits(x) __builtin_float_of_bits(x)
#define bits_of_float(x) __builtin_bits_of_float(x)
#else
union float_bits {
  float f;
  uint32_t i32;
};

float float_of_bits(uint32_t x) {
  union float_bits u;
  u.i32 = x;
  return u.f;
}
uint32_t bits_of_float(float x) {
  union float_bits u;
  u.f = x;
  return u.i32;
}
#endif

extern float mul(float, float);

int main() {
  float s = float_of_bits(UINT32_C(0xFF8FFFFF));
#ifdef EXTERN_MUL
  float q = mul(s, 1.0f);
#else
  float q = s * 1.0f;
#endif
  uint32_t s1 = bits_of_float(s);
  uint32_t q1 = bits_of_float(q);
  printf("%d\t%" PRIx32 "\t%" PRIx32 "\n", s1 == q1, s1, q1);
  return 0;
}
```

linked with

```
float mul(float x, float y) { return x*y; }
```

(two separate modules to prevent function inlining).

Comment: Annex F may or may not apply, possibly depending on compiler switches. What happens if you compile with `-frounding-math -fsignaling-nans`? NaN payloads are an optional, not a mandatory feature of IEEE-754 (i.e., an IEEE-754 "should"-provision, as opposed to a "shall"-provision). "To facilitate propagation of diagnostic information contained
in NaNs, as much of that information as possible should be preserved in NaN results of operations."

Comment: Re "if x is a signaling NaN, x * 1.0 will be a "quietified" version of it". That's the specified *masked* response to an SNaN, when the invalid operation exception is masked.

Comment: For a more equivalent compare, `float q = s * 1.0;` --> `float q = s * 1.0f;` (add `f` to avoid `double` math and conversions).  Also insightful to add `printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);`.  If that is non-zero, we have more issues to consider.

Comment: @chux Right. The results don't change with `1.0f`, `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is `0`. Assembly code examination shows that multiplication by the constant 1 is replaced by the identity.

Comment: Option `-fsignaling-nans` prevents this simplification indeed.

Comment: @DavidMonniaux Consider "The results don't change with 1.0f" on your machine.  As others investigate, good to use code that also will not raise stray concerns.

Comment: @DavidMonniaux I would suggest checking the gcc documentation. Many C and C++ compilers default to some sort of "medium performance" settings that disable *some* IEEE-754 features to gain performance. Users then have to manually add compiler switches to achieve strictest possible compliance. E.g. The Intel compiler uses `-fp-model=strict`, MSVC requires `/fp:strict`. I am not aware of such a catch-all switch for gcc, which appears to prefer making individual aspects of IEEE-754 (such as SNAN handling) selectable by compiler switch. No idea what Clang requires.

Comment: @DavidMonniaux When I last worked with compiler engineers, I handed them a copy of section "F.8.2 Expression transformations" from ISO-C99, requesting that they ensure all cases listed there work correctly at full optimizations. Depending on the context of your question, you may want to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for the options. My qiuestion is more like "is this allowed by the standard" than "how to disable it in gcc". ;) I'm working on another compiler, in which this optimization is prohibited, and am wondering if we could be laxer while still applying the standard.